# Compiling a class with a dependency in Java

Tags: java, compilation, dependencies, javac

Given the following classes:

```
package a.b;
public class C {
    public B b;
}
```

and, in a different file:

```
public class B {}
```

Standing in folder `folder`, executing

```
javac B.java
javac a/b/C.java -cp .
```

will generate `B.class` inside `folder` and will return a `Symbol not found` on the second command.

How (without making any modification to any of the classes B and C) can I compile `C.java`?

EDIT: maybe this can't be done

Comment: Your `Symbol not found` error is emitted because `javac` can't parse the variable declaration in `C.java`, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating both the classes in same java file then only one class has to be as declared "public" class. And the file name should be given as 
public class name.java

Also your way of creating an instance of class B is incorrect. It has to be done as follows:
B b = new B( );

Make sure to compile as:
javac -d . C.java

and make sure to remove the public access modifier from class B.

Comment: `public B b;` is correct (class field)

Both classes are on different files

Comment: If they are in different files then modify your line 3 as: B b = new B( ); and compile it using javac -d (directory of package a.b) B.java. This will make it work and make sure you have written your main method

Comment: The question says "without making any modification to any file"

Answer (score 0):

Why compile them separately?

```
javac B.java a/b/C.java
```

I believe this will work fine, since `javac` will be able to see both of your files.

You won't even need the `-cp` option, since you're already telling `javac` about everything you need.

Comment: I test this, It doesn't work.

And even if it worked it wouldn't have solved my problem.

Maybe this can't be done

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Is `javac` unable to locate one or both of the files, or does it emit an error while compiling a file?

Comment: The same error occurs, Symbol not found referring to type B of field b in class C

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why this shouldn't work. Maybe you could try an actual dependency management program like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/)?

Comment: Can't, I need to compile those two classes with javac

Comment: Are you sure you're passing in the arguments with `B.java` first? It may make a difference.

Comment: I copied what you wrote (ctrl-c + ctrl+v) and as I said, that wouldn't be a proper solution to my problem.

Maybe the problem can't be solved, but changing the problem is not a solution.